# Reinforcement Learning with Pytorch. [Error: KeyError ]

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am new to reinforcement learning as well as pytorch. I am learning it from Udemy. However, the code I have is the same as it is shown but I am having an error. I guess it is a pytorch error but can't debug it. If anyone helps it is really appreciated.

```
import gym
import time
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gym.envs.registration import register
register(id='FrozenLakeNotSlippery-v0',entry_point='gym.envs.toy_text:FrozenLakeEnv',kwargs={'map_name': '4x4', 'is_slippery':False})
env = gym.make('FrozenLakeNotSlippery-v0')
number_of_states = env.observation_space.n
number_of_actions = env.action_space.n
Q = torch.zeros([number_of_states,number_of_actions])
num_episodes = 1000
steps_total = []
gamma = 1
for i in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    step = 0
    while True:
        step += 1
        #action = env.action_space.sample()
        random_values = Q[state]+torch.rand(1,number_of_actions)/1000
        action = torch.max(random_values,1)[1][0]
        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        Q[state, action] = reward + gamma * torch.max(Q[new_state])
        state = new_state
        #time.sleep(0.4)
        #env.render()
        if done:
            steps_total.append(step)
            print ("Episode Finished after %i steps" %step)
            break

print ("Average Num Steps: %2f" %(sum(steps_total)/num_episodes))
plt.plot(steps_total)
plt.show()
```

The error I am having is the below one

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a6aa419c3767> in <module>
  8         random_values = Q[state]+torch.rand(1,number_of_actions)/1000
  9         action = torch.max(random_values,1)[1][0]
---> 10         new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
 11         Q[state, action] = reward + gamma * torch.max(Q[new_state])
 12         state = new_state

c:\users\souradip\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\toy_text\discrete.py in step(self, a)
 53 
 54     def step(self, a):
---> 55         transitions = self.P[self.s][a]
 56         i = categorical_sample([t[0] for t in transitions], self.np_random)
 57         p, s, r, d= transitions[i]

KeyError: tensor(3)
```

Comment: Try `a.item()`.

Comment: thank you I will definitely try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code

```
action = torch.max(random_values,1)[1][0]
```

results in a `0-dim` tensor, but `env.step()` expects a python number, which is basically an action from the action space. So, as [@a_guest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3767239/a-guest) mentioned in the comment, use `a.item()` to convert a `0-dim` tensor to a python number like below:

```
new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action.item())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely try it out and one more thing. Is there any good link or tutorial which provides how to code for my custom environment. Since most of the links show reinforcement learning tutorial for the gym provided environment. What if I want to train my RL agent on an environment which is not provided by gym. 
Like I am thinking to work in Intrusion detection using reinforcement learning. So those kind environment is not available in gym .